# Can't open Pimcore admin interface even after giving path of public folder in xampp apache (httpd.conf)

Tags: pimcore

I was also facing issue regarding Pimcore as I am installing it on windows 10 (remote desktop[Azure VM]). But in my case I can't found .htaccess file in public folder in pimcore folder. It should look like this pimcore/public/.htaccess but there is no .htaccess file in public folder so that I can configure anything.
Secondly, docker process, I am facing issue like if I try to download docker in my azure vm it gives me error like system requirement is not fulfilled even after doing everything. I am stuck in this.

I tried installing pimcore several times and every time I am facing same error issue. I am following installation guide of pimcore step by step and also followed some youtube videos but still getting this issue.
*Problem what I configured is I can't found .htaccess file in public folder. (please correct me if I am wrong).*
Please help me regarding this I need solution as soon as possible.
Any help would be appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjIVY.png)

I did configuration for .htaccess file but getting error
"The Symfony\Polyfill\Intl\Icu\Locale::getPrimaryLanguage() is not implemented. Please install the "intl" extension for full localization capabilities."[Here you can see the screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znSND.png)
I will be obliged to you for helping, Can't find solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

first check system requirement from command :- bin/console pimcore:system:requirements:check

for .htaccess you can copy from below url into web/ folder

https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/6.9/Development_Documentation/Installation_and_Upgrade/System_Setup_and_Hosting/Apache_Configuration.html

Comment: I did what you suggest but getting this issue, and can't find solution     "The Symfony\Polyfill\Intl\Icu\Locale::getPrimaryLanguage() is not implemented. Please install the "intl" extension for full localization capabilities."